Python - KeyUp/ on_release_key event gets lost when I press keys too fast
I tried to simulate that a key gets spammed in a game when I hold that specific key. It works fine except that sometimes my key-release does get lost when I press many keys in a short period of time and so my code runs infinite because my on_release_key is the point where my simulated key-spam stops. It continues as intended when I press my key again (until the event gets lost again), but I wondered if there is a way to "speed up" my button-processing or something so that my event does not get lost.
Your help and/or alternative solutions are very much appreciated!
I already confirmed that the key release gets lost as I printed counters of my key-presses and key-releases and that showed a difference in my key-releases.
import keyboard
import time
import threading

key_pressed = False

def press_key(key):
    while key_pressed:
        keyboard.send(key)
        time.sleep(0.2)

def on_key_down(event, key):
    global key_pressed
    if event.name == key:
        key_pressed = True
        threading.Thread(target=press_key, args=(key,), daemon=True).start()

def on_key_up(event, key):
    global key_pressed
    if event.name == key:
        key_pressed = False

key_to_replicate = 'k'

keyboard.on_press_key(key_to_replicate, 
                      lambda event: on_key_down(event, key_to_replicate))
keyboard.on_release_key(key_to_replicate, 
                        lambda event: on_key_up(event, key_to_replicate))

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


The issue you're facing is due to the way you're handling key presses and releases using the keyboard library. When you press multiple keys in a short period, some key release events might get lost, causing your simulated key spam to continue indefinitely.
import keyboard
import time
import threading

key_pressed = False
key_to_replicate = 'k'

def key_spammer(key):
    global key_pressed
    while key_pressed:
        keyboard.press_and_release(key)
        time.sleep(0.2)

def on_key_down(event):
    global key_pressed
    if event.name == key_to_replicate:
        key_pressed = True
        threading.Thread(target=key_spammer, args=(key_to_replicate,), daemon=True).start()

def on_key_up(event):
    global key_pressed
    if event.name == key_to_replicate:
        key_pressed = False

keyboard.on_press_key(key_to_replicate, on_key_down)
keyboard.on_release_key(key_to_replicate, on_key_up)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


Sadly this did not work and with this code the events get also lost after I clicked multiple keys very fast and the counters of both key up and down events do have a difference of a couple (2-4) after 40 very fast inputs of my key combined with other buttons.
